# Strange Typescript compiler Error: 'this' cannot be referenced in current location, Can anyone explain please?

Tags: typescript

I presume there is a good reason for this but it seems very strange to me.  Please take the following code as an example of the issue.

```
class Foo {
    constructor(referenceMethod: () => void) {
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

    TestProperty: string = "boo";

    constructor() {
        super(this.ReferenceMethod);
    }

    ReferenceMethod() {

    }
}
```

This produces the compiler error

> 'this' cannot be referenced in current location.

If we initialise the `TestProperty` inside the constructor the compiler is happy and the world spins round as expected and of course if we don't pass the reference to the referenceMethod to the super call we can set the TestProperty outside the constructor fine.

However I just don't understand why doing both these things together causes a problem.  If anyone could shed some light on this to help my understanding would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

From 8.3.2 of the [Typescript language specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf):

> The first statement in the body of a constructor must be a **super** call
>   if both of the following are true:
>      1. The containing class is a  derived class.
>      2. The constructor declares parameter properties or the containing class declares
>         instance member variables with initializers.

The containing class in your example declares a variable called `TestProperty` that uses an initializer:

```
 TestProperty: string = "boo";
```

The reason for the error you're seeing is that the compiler requires the first line of the `constructor` to be the call to the `super` given the current layout of your class (#2 from the language specification above). Because of that, it means that the class isn't fully initialized when you start to reference properties on the class, like `TestProperty`. While `ReferenceMethod` would be initialized and available, the member variables still would not be, which could break other functionality in your class.

While the language authors could have generated working code that avoids this issue, it's clearly easier and more consistent behavior when it works the way you've found.

As an alternative, you might try adding an `initialize` method that performs the same logic once the constructor has initialized the class fully. It's admittedly a second step, but, it works well with TypeScript. But, be careful to make sure that initialize is called **after** the constructor has initialized member variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the lateness of mine.  I think I see what you are saying, while in this instance everything should work fine, If I was referencing an instance variable that was declared below the constructor we would be passing an undefined reference.  
Although I do wonder if this is an overly strict rule, and we get to know when properties and functions are in scope.  
Although maybe it is more user friendly to be a little more on the strict side.
Anyhow thanks once more for the reply.

Comment: It's the choice the language designers made.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `Foo` and `Bar` have different behaviors.  `Foo` accepts a callback as its constructor but `Bar` has the callback as an instance method.  What is your real-world use case?  Perhaps `Bar` should compose (contain) `Foo` and not extend it.

Alternatively you can modify the behavior of `Foo` to accept an optional callback and also define an overridable instance method that is used as default.  Then the derived class can ignore the callback argument and just override the instance method instead.

*Option 1: Composition*

```
class Foo {
    constructor(referenceMethod: () => void) {
    }
}

class Bar {

    TestProperty: string = "boo";
    foo: Foo;

    constructor() {
        this.foo = new Foo(this.ReferenceMethod);
    }

    ReferenceMethod() {

    }
}
```

*Option 2: Reference method as optional arg and overridable*

```
class Foo {
    constructor(referenceMethod?: () => void) {
        if (referenceMethod) {
            this.ReferenceMethod = referenceMethod;
        }
    }

    ReferenceMethod():void {}
}

class Bar {

    TestProperty: string = "boo";

    constructor() {
    }

    ReferenceMethod():void {

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems OK that `Bar` has a default behavior for the `ReferenceMethod`. That doesn't need to be solved by doing a composition model.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, thanks for your opinion.  I figured some would disagree, that's why I included the alternate inheritance model that also solves the OP's issue.

Comment: But `Bar` isn't a `Foo` in either example?

Answer (score 0):

If someone steps with this error, also happens when using the `private` or `public` modifiers inside a constructor.

Try:

```
constructor(x : number) {
    ... super call with this reference
    this.x = x;
}

private x : number;
```

Instead of:

```
constructor(private x: number) {
     ...super calls, compiler error here
}
```